# Start Rails server automatically on Ubuntu startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, ubuntu

I need to run my Rails server upon system startup. I am running my ROR code in my Ubuntu server. Here i need to see my rails server always in start condition. Suppose the Ubuntu server has shut down for some problem when it will start again my Rails server should start automatically. For this i made a script which is given below:

```
cd /home/subhrajyoti/spa
rails server -p 8888 -b 10.25.25.100 -d
```

In windows I am putting this file in the `Windows Startup` folder and it's running automatically each time Windows starts. Now I need the same behaviour in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out might help with your issue 
[Link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226535)